# Watson Assistant: Problem with extracting value for pattern entity

Tags: regex, ibm-cloud, entity, watson-assistant

I am trying to get the value for the first group match of a pattern entity from the json response of Watson Assistant. The pattern is a simple regex to recognize sequences of numbers: ([0-9]+)

The json response looks like this:

```
    "entity": "ID",
    "location": [
      18,
      23
    ],
    "value": "id",
    "confidence": 1.0,
    "groups": [
      {
        "group": "group_0",
        "location": [
          18,
          23
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "entity": "sys-number",
    "location": [
      18,
      23
    ],
    "value": "12345",
    "confidence": 1.0,
    "metadata": {
      "numeric_value": 12345.0
    }
  }
]
```

So, the group is matched alright, but the field "value" is populated with the String literal from the entity config. I would expected to find the actual value there (which is the one the value field of the next entity, sys-number).

How do I need to change the config so that the value is included as-is in the value field (or somewhere else) and so that I don't have to extract the entity from the text string using the location values? Is it possible at all?
Thanks a lot

Cheers, 
Martin

Comment: Where do you perform the regex? Why not use a JSON path expression?

Comment: The regex is how you configure an entity pattern in the Watson assistang setup. I didn't mean that I use the Regex to parse the Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access value of pattern based entity, you can either use `<? @entity_name.literal ?>` or `<? @entity_name.groups[0] ?>` - if there are more groups captured. You can find more info in the doc: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-entities